# Showing a window on ListItem pressed

Tags: android

I have a List Item in my Main Actitivy that takes in local File objects (custom class):

```
public static ArrayList<localFile> inventoryItems = new ArrayList<localFile>();
```

I initialized a Dialog also in my Main Activity:

```
Dialog weaponDialog;
```

Then in the on Create Method i did this:

```
Dialog weaponDialog = new Dialog(this);
    weaponDialog.setContentView(R.layout.weapon_info);
```

The content view of the weapon Dialog now is set to a custom made view created in XML:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/shipInfoView"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inv"
    android:background="@drawable/green_border_full"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:maxLength="40"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:textColor="@color/Green"
    android:textSize="12sp" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plrLvl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="   Damage:"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wpnDamage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wpnWeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="   Weight:   "
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wpnWeightA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="   Rarity:"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wpnRarity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The said listView has an ItemClick Listener:

```
        inventoryList.setClickable(true);
    inventoryList
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    localFile file = (localFile) inventoryList
                            .getItemAtPosition(position);
                    showItem(file);
                }
            });
}
```

And each time i click an Item in the list View, a dialog box should appear containing the information from the file that is passed in just above ^ :

```
    public void showItem(localFile file) {
    TextView wpnName = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    TextView wpnDmg = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.wpnDamage);
    TextView wpnWei = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.wpnWeightA);
    TextView wpnRar = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.wpnRarity);
    wpnName.setText(file.name);
    String sizeStr = String.valueOf(file.size);
    wpnDmg.setText(sizeStr);
    wpnWei.setText(sizeStr);
    weaponDialog.show();
}
```

Every Time i press an item in the List view, i get a null Pointer exception in my show Item method. This is caused by this line:

```
weaponDialog.show();
```

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Create a custom Alert Dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declared dialog as a global but again with same variable name you initalized the dialog locally.so global variable is not initialized it is null.

```
Dialog weaponDialog = new Dialog(this);
```

So in this line delete `Dialog` here it is a local variable..so and change it into

```
weaponDialog = new Dialog(this);
```

and try.set the dialog text also..

Comment: Im trying it now :) Thank you for the fast reply :)

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked :) Just goes to show how one little word can make a huge difference :)